# Can we edit bootstrap css style without download the packaging?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I used a lot of bootstrap template that I didn't download, when I open the 'inspect' to change the color etc it show a ..bootstrap.min.scss (something like that) link that I can't even open. Is it posibble to modified the template without having the css file in our computer?

Comment: what do you want to modified in the template?

Answer (score 0):

you can always override the styles applied by a framework or external style sheet by creating rules that are more specific. Let's say the bootstrap code styles your links, you will have to create a more specific rule that overrules the previous in your own style sheet on your local machine.

Let's say bootstrap styles the `a` tag, you can give your body a class like:

```
<body id="cherry">
    <a href="#">my link</a>
</body>
```

in your css file:

```
#cherry a {
    color: magenta;
}
```

For further reading I recommend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity